# Python and binary data in regexps

Tags: python

I am looking for a way of putting non-printable characters in a string in python.

Small background information: I am working with windows command prompt over SSH using paramiko. however paramiko does not 'parse'/'work with' the ANSI Terminal Emulation escape sequences. So they are appearing in my output, which I do not want. So I need to strip-off these escape sequences.

These strings/escape sequences however are encoded in the following manner: `Esc[Line;ColumnH`

And as you can guess. I can't get the esc-byte value in a string. It will either print as, well, something like `0x1b` or `27`. Thus useless.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Escape the non-ascii characters (by replacing with literals), do regex magic, un-escape?

Comment: with many applications, setting environment variable TERM=dumb will prevent them from sending ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: @PauloScardine sadly, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress these escape sequences using regex :

```
str_with_ainsi_esc = '\x1b[10;10HSalut'
print re.sub('\x1b\[\d+;\d+H','',str_with_ainsi_esc)
```

Comment: Ahh, so that is how you put byte-chars in a string. Thanks. Will take a closer look tomorrow. (home-time now)

Comment: I did change `'\x1b\[\d+;\d+H'` to `'\x1b\[\d*;\d*H'` because both the column and row value are optional according to the VT100 spec.